# C# DateTime column in DataTable stores Culture specific DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I assigned the DateTime value to DateTime type column of DataTable:

```
colName["businessDate"] = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

now, my system date time is set to format 5/12/2016 8:11 a.m. ,when I assigned the above culture.invariant DateTime value ,column still stores culture specific DateTime value.

---

note: I want to store AM/PM standard format through culture.invariant , also I can not change table structure or column data type.

Comment: Well if the type of the column is `DateTime`, then you're storing a `DateTime`, which doesn't have a culture or a format. It's important to differentiate between a value and its text representation.

Comment: @JonSkeet sir I need to store DateTime value forcibly with AM/PM representation in DateTime column, so converting system DateTime to Culture.invariant gives me AM/PM exactly regardless of any tt format set.

Comment: but i am unable to store Culture.Invariant date value to data column

Comment: No, you've missed the point. That's like saying "I need to store an `int` value in hex." Only a *text* representation has AM/PM. The `DateTime` value doesn't have *any* formatting knowledge, any more than an int does.

Comment: This basically sounds like something you should address by formatting the data appropriately when you want to display it. Formatting should almost never be a concern of storage.

Comment: @JonSkeet sir i got your point, kindly solve my little problem when I DateTime.Parse(column["businessdate"].ToString())    , column["businessdate"]="5/12/2016 8:29 a.m." it does not parse it because of "a.m." .. even if  i set tt value to xyz in windows calender it stores it. any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `DateTime.Parse` at all? It should already be a `DateTime` if it's a `DateTime` column in the `DataTable`... Basically, you should be avoiding string conversions unless they're absolutely necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111755/discussion-between-ayazz-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: @JonSkeet I will try to correct my direction with your provided suggestions. thanks a lot sir for your precious time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet i have datetime column in datatable and i just going to store DateTime.Now() value in datetime column then to i got below error.                                            ** Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <2019-04-18 07:35:05 AM> in dOrderDate Column.  Expected type is DateTime. **   May you plz help me?

Comment: @HardikLeuwa: Please ask a new question with a [mcve]. It sounds like your column isn't of the right type. (In most cases I'd recommend storing `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now`, by the way - but that's a whole different conversation.)